# wkhtmltopdf runtime for many pdf-creations

Tags: performance, session, runtime, screen, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf on my ubuntu server to generate pdfs out of html-templates.

wkhtmltopdf is therefore started from a php-script with shell_exec.

My problem is, that I want to create up to 200 pdfs at (almost) the same time, which makes the runtime of wkhtmltopdf kind of stack for every pdf. One file needs 0.6 seconds, 15 files need 9 seconds.

My idea was to start wkhtmltopdf in a screen-session to decrease the runtime, but I can't make it work from php plus this might not make that much sense, because I want to additionally summarize all pdfs in one after creation, so I would have to check if every session is terminated?!

Do you have any ideas how I can decrease the runtime for this amount of pdfs or can you give me advice how to realize this correctly and smart with screen?

My script looks like the following:

```
loop up to 200times {
- get data for html-template from database
- fill template-string and write .html-file
- create pdf out of html-template via shell_exec("wkhtmltopdf....")
- delete template-file
}

merge all generated pdfs together to one and send it via mail
```

Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english.

best wishes

Answer (score 0):

Just create a single large HTML file and convert it in one pass instead of merging multiple PDFs afterwards.

Comment: But I also want to get the single pdfs

Comment: That wasn't in the original question ... in that case you might want to use `--read-args-from-stdin` and pipe the requests.